# Using sed to strip parentheses from a string

Tags: regex, unix, sed

I am trying to use *sed*(1) to remove parentheses from strings, but only when the parentheses begin with a particular string. For example, I want to change a string such as `Song Name (f/ featured artist) (Remix)`, to `Song Name f/ featuredartist (Remix)`. How can I achieve this?

I am currently trying the following:

```
echo "Song Name (f/ featuredartist) (Remix)" | sed s/"(f\/ [a-z]*)"/"f\/ "/
```

But all this does is return `Song Name f/  (Remix)`.

Also note: Anything goes between `f/` and `)`, not just `[a-z]*` as my working attempt would imply.

Comment: You need to work with capture groups (don't know if they are available in sed, look them up).

Comment: Anything goes? Is that so? Wow about (f/ (/f nested) featuredartist).  That falls under "anything". Which paren is the closing one?

Comment: @kaz the output in that case would be "f/ (/f nested) featuredartist"

Comment: If you want to handle arbitrary nesting, you *cannot* solve your problem with regular expressions.

Comment: Not with regular expressions that are regular. However, some recent tools have "regular" expressions that are not in fact regular.

Comment: @segfault so in other words the nesting is still recognized, but the inner f/ is not processed. Of course I meant `(f/ (f/ nested) featuredartist)` not `/f`.

Comment: @Kaz yeah, I meant that I only care about the outer-most `(f/...)` grouping. Certainly was worth mentioning though, and a good point. Fortunately, I don't expect such cases to occur. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This might work for you:

```
echo "Song Name (f/ featuredartist) (Remix)" | sed 's|(\(f/[^)]*\))|\1|'
Song Name f/ featuredartist (Remix)
```

Comment: This does it. Thanks! Would you mind a quick explanation of the syntax in the sed command? I have a general knowledge of regular expressions, but am hoping to understand the usage of \1 in sed commands.

Comment: See [here](http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html#toc-uh-4) for an explanation (and an altogether good tutorial).

Answer (score 1):

```
echo 'Song Name (f/ featured artist) (Remix)' | sed 's/\(.*\)(\(f\/[^)]\+\))/\1\2/'
```

Comment: I presume you are trying to do something simular to what is explained here: http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html#uh-4 however, that specific line is failing to strip the parentheses.

Comment: @segfault, is there anything wrong with this one? It works on the example

Comment: the line you gave in the response didnt even work when I tried it in my shell

Answer (score 1):

TXR solution ( http://www.nongnu.org/txr ).

```
@;; a texts is a collection of text pieces
@;; with no gaps in between.
@;;
@(define texts (out))@\
  @(coll :gap 0)@(textpiece out)@(end)@\
  @(cat out "")@\
@(end)
@;;
@;; recursion depth indicator
@;;
@(bind recur 0)
@;;
@;; a textpiece is a paren unit,
@;; or a sequence of chars other than parens.
@;; or, else, in the non-recursive case only,
@;; any character.
@;;
@(define textpiece (out))@\
   @(cases)@\
     @(paren out)@\
   @(or)@\
     @{out /[^()]+/}@\
   @(or)@\
     @(bind recur 0)@\
     @{out /./}@\
   @(end)@\
@(end)
@;;
@;; a paren unit consists
@;; of ( followed by a space-delimited token
@;; followed by some texts (in recursive mode)
@;; followed by a closing paren ).
@;; Based on what the word is, we transform
@;; the text.
@;;
@(define paren (out))@\
  @(local word inner level)@\
  @(bind level recur)@\
  @(local recur)@\
  @(bind recur @(+ level 1))@\
  (@word @(texts inner))@\
  @(cases)@\
    @(bind recur 1)@\
    @(bind word ("f/") ;; extend list here
           )@\
    @(bind out inner)@\
  @(or)@\
    @(bind out `(@word @inner)`)@\
  @(end)@\
@(end)
@;; scan standard input in freeform (as one big line)
@(freeform)
@(texts out)@trailjunk
@(output)
@out@trailjunk
@(end)
```

Sample run:

```
$ txr paren.txr -
a b c d
[Ctrl-D]
a b c d

$ txr paren.txr -
The quick brown (f/ ox jumped over the (f/ lazy) dogs). (
The quick brown ox jumped over the (f/ lazy) dogs. (
```

Comment: The `recur` variable is a dynamically scoped hack. The `texts` pattern function must only recognize an arbitrary single character in the non-nested case, otherwise it will eat a closing parenthesis. In `paren` we use the nesting level to only strip the parentheses when `f/` occurs in the first recursion level. However, we recognize the nesting of parentheses regardless.

Comment: That makes recursive patterns in Perl and PCRE look easy.

Comment: The rebinding of `recur` is very clumsy with that temporary variable `level`. I've just introduced a `rebind` directive which does this in one step: `@(rebind recur @(+ 1 recur)). The expression is evaluated in the environment in which the previous `recur` binding is visible, but then a new binding is established for `recur` which takes the value. That's in git now and of course will be released in TXR 63.

Comment: Show you the code? Not tonight, it’s too late for me. But here’s a short example of matching a function call name along with its potentially recursively nested parentheses delimiting its argument list: `/\w+ ( \( (?: [^()]++ | (?-1) )*+ \) )/x`.

Comment: The code in this answer doesn't simply match nested parentheses. The patterns have actions. Just matching nested brackets can be done with a pattern function like this `@(define paren)@(maybe)[@(coll)@(paren)@(until)]@(end)]@(end)@(end)` which is easier to understand than some serial line noise. (This is from the Balanced Brackets task here which uses square brackets: http://www.nongnu.org/txr/rosetta-solutions.html). It will match things like `[a[b c]d][e[]]` and leave a non-matching suffix in the input. If you see a [, then collect bracketed stuff until you see ]. Then match the ].